# devexpress aspxgridview - custom text for paging

Tags: asp.net, aspxgridview, custompaging

Is there a way to customize the top and bottom paging display? Like I want to display the

Top as "Now displaying 1 - 10 of 1000 records for ".
Bottom page as normal grid style like [1][2]...

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this:

```
<SettingsPager Summary-Text="Page {0} of {1} ({2} Widgets found) "></SettingsPager>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the grid properties there is a SettingsPager group. Under Summary there are two options which allow you to change the text for the pager.
If you want to change the position go to SettingsPager >> Position.